# Correção de texto

Tags: pronomes, concordância-verbal, regência

Vi em um restaurante a seguinte frase de homenagem ao dia dos pais:

[image]

No Brasil, este ano o dia dos pais foi comemorado no dia 14 de agosto.

Não seria melhor:

> Pai, agradeço-lhe por tudo que você fez e faz por mim até hoje.
>   Você é essencial em minha vida!
>  Te amo! Parabéns pelo seu dia.

Qual a melhor forma de reescrever essa frase? Por que?

Comment: Não me parece haver qualquer problema em nenhuma das duas versões.  Acho que a melhor forma é um bocado subjectivo, mas deixa ver o que respondem.

Comment: No linguagem formal eu prefiro usar sempre o mesmo pronome pessoal. Se começo com a segunda pessoa do singular, eu a mantenho até o fim.  Idem com a terceira pessoa.

Comment: Se queres evitar a chamada mistura de tratamentos, então, com *você*, é *o amo* ou *amo-o*. Creio que também há quem diga no Brasil *lhe amo* e *amo você*, mas não sei se isso é mais bem visto que a mistura de tratamentos.

Comment: Acho que seria uma boa ressaltar no seu texto quais as alterações que vês necessárias, além de deixar mais claro o título da questão (que esta bem genérico).

Answer (score 2):

No padrão brasileiro, nenhuma das duas. O correto seria:

> Pai, quero lhe agradecer por tudo que você fez e faz por mim até hoje.
>
> Você é essencial em minha vida!
>
> **Amo você**! Parabéns pelo teu dia.

No coloquial brasileiro, a frase do restaurante é melhor; "agradeço-lhe" é formal demais.

Em Portugal, creio que se usaria "tu" em vez "de você" em toda a construção:

> Pai, quero agradecer-**te** por tudo o que **fizeste** e **fazes** por mim até hoje.
>
> **És** essencial na minha vida!
>
> **Amo-te**! Parabéns pelo **teu** dia.

Mas é simplesmente a impressão de quem vê as coisas de longe.

Comment: Luís corrigi ali, em Portugal diz-se "na minha vida". Acho que o "até hoje" também desaparecia, mas não fica mal de todo.

Comment: @JorgeB. Grato!

Comment: Em Portugal, é também possível que este parágrafo seja escrito em tom formal: `Pai, quero agradecer-lhe por tudo o que fez e faz por mim até hoje. Você é essencial na minha vida! Amo-o, parabéns pelo seu dia.` Há famílias para tudo...